# Xcode fails to properly sign framework when debugging iOS app on a device

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, code-signing

I'm running into an annoying problem that I'm hoping someone can shed some light on. We have an iOS framework that is built outside of Xcode and is embedded in our iOS app. Running (debugging) the app via Xcode (9.4) works great on a simulator.

The problem is that when we run (debug) it on a device, the install fails with this error:

> installd: 0x16f9eb000 +[MICodeSigningVerifier _validateSignatureAndCopyInfoForURL: withOptions: error: ]: 147: Failed to verify code signature of /private/ var/ installd/ Library/ Caches/ com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/ temp.BGuE4G/ extracted/ MyApp.app/ Frameworks/ MyFramework.framework : 0xe8008001 (An unknown error has occurred.)

If I change the app target's signing identity/profile to distribution/ad hoc and run (debug) it, then it installs just fine (but course, doesn't let you actually attach to the process since it was signed for distribution). Then if I change the identity/profile back to development (without rebuilding the framework) and run it again, then it launches on the device and the debugger attaches just fine.

I can then edit-build-debug the app as many times as I like and it works great on the device every time. But as soon as I rebuild the framework and then run the app, I get the error again and have to repeat the process of switching to distribution and back before I can debug it.

So it appears to me that Xcode isn't properly signing the framework each time I run it - I have to trigger the signing myself by switching to distribution and back to development any time the framework changes. I've tried cleaning the app's project and derived data after rebuilding the framework but I still get the error.

I'd appreciate any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further or simply how to avoid needing to change the signing settings every time we change the framework (which is very frequent).

Thanks!

Comment: have you created universal framework? usually, I have seen this problem when we build our framework for certain architecture like simulator/device specific.

Comment: Hi Prakash, the framework includes both simulator and device architectures (arm64, armv7, armv7s, i386, x86_64). Interesting idea, though, that it might be related to the architectures, I'll do some testing...